# UTF-8 encode not working properly on Greek characters

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, encoding, character-encoding

For some reason when I'm trying to encode a JSON file that I've downloaded from SSMS, the encoding of Greek characters in VS code come out as question marks.

This is my code:

```
import json

def combine_lines(json_path):
    with open(json_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
        json_data = file.read()

    json_data = json_data.replace('\n', '')
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_data)
    formatted_json = json.dumps(parsed_json, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    return formatted_json

json_path = r'D:\jazon.json'
result = combine_lines(json_path)
print(result)
```

This is an output example:

```
 {
        "Man_Name": "�� ��� ��� ����",
        "countbar": "977110"
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is kind of beautify the JSON I have but something goes wrong with the Greek characters (they are printed as question marks). I'm a newbie so there might be an obvious answer that I don't know. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're not encoding. When you call `open(json_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')` you are decoding the bytes in that file, and you are saying that the bytes were encoded with `utf-8-sig`. If that's not working, then I'd assume the problem is most likely that the file was not encoded with that encoding.

Comment: More likely a font problem; the program reads and displays the glyphs just fine as far as the Python mechanics are involved, but your GUI lacks a font with the correct glyphs, or is otherwise misconfigured. Python would throw an exception if it wasn't able to decode the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with the output of VS code. I exported the printed JSON into a text file and it seems that the Greek characters are visible.